# Vertical Spacing Between the Chapter and Section Titles

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, vertical-spacing

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{CHAPTER I}
\section*{The Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How may I (in this case) reduce the vertical spacing between the Chapter title and the beginning of the Section title? Also, is there a way to specify the amount of vertical space between the Section title and the start of the text? (In this case, I would like to increase it a bit.)

Comment: Are you using `\chapter{CHAPTER I}` to manually number chapters and the combination of `\chapter*` and `\section*` to make the “CHAPTER“ in upper and much bigger than chapter title? If so, please don't! Instead reconfigure the chapter headings. There are [packages like `titlesec` to do reconfiguration of headings](https://ctan.org/topic/headings) for the standard classes. There are also other classes like `scrbook` (from KOMA-Script) or `memoir`, that provide an interface to do such configurations.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, you can use the `titlesec` package; for example, as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\huge}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{15pt}

% Spacing between section and text
% Syntax: \titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{.65cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{CHAPTER I}
\section*{The Section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The parameter values, of course, can be adjusted.